# Where's the # key in Lion

Tags: macos, keyboard

In Snow Leopard alt-3 used to print a #, in Lion it doesn't. 
I'v tried different key combination keyboard viewer but still no luck.
Any ideas were the # key went?

Comment: It depends heavily on the localization you set - what layout are you using? (It is selected when you first customize your OS and can be changed in the **Language & Text** system preference under _Input Sources_ )

Comment: Any chance you're on a UK keyboard? Or UK keyboard setting at least? If so, try `Alt+3`...

Comment: I have my Input Source configured to U.S.

Comment: It's Shift-3 even tough I have the £ sign on my 3 >.<

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since it varies by keyboard layout - why not open your keyboard viewer and find out?

In the US keyboard layout on lion, it's still <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>

[image]

You have to select this from the menu bar after enabling it in the menu bar

[image]

Comment: The post author did mention trying keyboard viewer.  But perhaps did not hit shift or alt+shift?

Comment: More likely the input source was changer on her.

Answer (score 2):

It's still Alt-3 on my UK keyboard -- ###.

Comment: apparently uk keyboard has alt-3 as # & shift 3 as £; the U.S. keyboard is vice versa

Comment: this is correct, alt-3 for # on UK keyboard

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the widget:

### [CharacterPal](https://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/reference/characterpal.html)

Searching and copying a needed character is faster than with the keyboard viewer:

- You do can look through all characers at once. With the keyboard viewer you need to hold <kbd>⌥</kbd> and <kbd>⇧</kbd> to see more characters.
- Characters are sorteded by type: greek, keyboard, math...
- **TOP**: You can find special (keyboard) symbols like <kbd>⌦</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>, <kbd>⎋</kbd>, <kbd>⏏</kbd>, <kbd>⌤</kbd> ...

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

on a french keyboard # is: alt-shift-£

crazy huh?

Answer (score -2):

You're talking about the hash key? Doesn't it print when you press Shift+3 ? Or maybe your keyboard layout is different but on every keyboard I've seen in the United States that's where the hash key lives.

Comment: Perhaps the questioner isn't in the United States? Apple keyboards in the UK have no hash symbol marked on them at all, but you can get hash with Alt-3 (in Lion as well as Snow Leopard). Similarly, the Euro symbol € is Alt-2, which *is* marked on the keyboard, and Alt-1 and Alt-4 through Alt-0 also produce different unmarked characters.

Comment: ¡™£¢∞§¶•ªº–≠ alt is fun ⁄€‹›ﬁﬂ‡°·‚—± how much comes out when non-Macs view this web page?

Comment: I can see all of that from the windows computer I use for work. Why?