# How can I do shift + slash on a French AZERTY keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, customization, internationalization

I have a MacBook with a French AZERTY keyboard.
On this keyboard, the forward slash ('/') is over the ':' character, so I have to do: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd> to get the <kbd>/</kbd>.

However in Eclipse there is a useful shortcut to comment out blocks of code: you do <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> to put "//" at the beginning of every line of selected code; and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> to put /* and */ at the beginning and the end of selected lines, thus commenting out the block of code.

But as I already need to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> to get the <kbd>/</kbd>, when I do <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd>, it understands <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>, and I get the first shortcut.

I can't seem to get the second shortcut. I even tried <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd>, using both Shift keys on my keyboard, and of course it didn't work.

I worked around that by changing Eclipse shortcuts, but I was curious to know if there is a way to achieve that (reaching <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>).

I hope you clearly understand this is a matter of the highest importance...

Comment: I suggest asking the Eclipse people.  If there isn't such a shortcut now for your keyboard, they may be interested in creating one for a future version.

Answer (score 2):

As described in [several](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8787/swap-key-permanently/8788#8788) [posts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2767/how-can-i-disable-the-decimal-comma-on-a-spanish-keyboard-layout/2768#2768), the [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) program works to redefine the keyboard if you don't like the default layout.

You can at least find the right key using the Keyboard Viewer - steps on that are here: [Where's the # key in Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21460/wheres-the-key-in-lion/21466#21466)