# How to use a shortcut with a special character which requires ALT or SHIFT key to be pressed?

Tags: keyboard, catalina, internationalization

I have an application which has some shortcuts defined in combination with some special characters:

[image]

On my keyboard's layout, to get a forward slash character (`/`) I have to press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>. I tried to press all three required keys (<kbd>COMMAND</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>) but the shortcut wasn't triggered. If I change my keyboard layout to US for example, shortcut works fine.

Is there a way to use such shortcuts with my existing layout or should I switch my layout to US if I want to be able to use them?

Comment: Did you try pretending your layout is US, by hitting the key on which / would be printed if you had a us keyboard?

Comment: [How can I do shift + slash on a French AZERTY keyboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21858/how-can-i-do-shift-slash-on-a-french-azerty-keyboard?rq=1)

Comment: @TomGewecke Yes, I actually tried that, but it, of course, only prints out a specific character from my current layout which is located in that key.

Comment: @ankii Thanks for the link, but I'd really like to find out if it is possible without any keyboard remapping and/or 3rd party software.

Comment: What is your keyboard layout?  Command plus a top level key should not normally print anything.  It would not do so in the US layout.  This is reserved for shortcuts.